# Save modifications in Azure Workbook

Tags: azure, edit, azureportal

I want to save a modified Azure Workbook. But after I click on *Done editing* I can not leave the page and move back to the resource group I get the message

```
Your unsaved edits will be discarded.
```

Do I miss to click on something? I can see the save icon, but when I click on that it just wants to store it in a new workbook and not in the existing one.

Comment: You have a Save option beside done editing tab. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7fP3.png)

Comment: That's right, but when I click on that it opens up a menu to save the workbook as a new workbook, but don't let me save the changes in the current workbook.

Comment: You can see the workbook which i have  saved with name [MyWorkBook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8ZO8.png) in the given [resource group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFM1u.png)

Comment: Okay, so when I do a change on MyWorkbook and want to save that change I have to create MyWorkbook2, because when I write MyWorkbook I get *A Workbook with the same name already exists within this subscription.*

Comment: Please check [Auto refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNF7g.png) once

Comment: I added autorefresh with setting of 5 min, waited the 5 min and also manually clicked on refresh. That didn't changed anything for saving the changes. I still got the message, that I would lose my data.

Comment: Ok..will look into it and let you know

Comment: I solved the problem, but dear lord... I opened the workbook within the resource group which let me to the problem. When I open it via the Azure Monitor I can save the changes. The UI is sometime quite confusing. But thank you very much for your help and time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears, when I opened the workbook via the resource group. In that view I was unable to save the changes.

This was solved by opening the Azure Workbook via the Azure Monitor. A click on the save icon stores the changes in the current workbook.